# array_filter without strip keys with false value

Tags: php, arrays

I've this array:

```
[
  'a' => true,
  'b' => false,
  'c' = null,
  'd' = 'foo'
]
```

I need to strip from it only the `null` keys and keep all the rest.

```
[
  'a' => true,
  'b' => false,
  'd' = 'foo'
]
```

I've tried with **`array_filter`** but it strips even the `false` keys, how can I do?

Comment: Where is your current code?

Comment: I've tried with array_filter, do I need to write array_filter($var)? Remove the -1 please

Comment: I didn't downvote your question if you mean me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide an **explicit** callback to test for null

```
$array = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($value) {
        return $value !== null;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function ($value) { return $value !== null; });
```

Comment: Note: anonymous functions (http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) available since PHP 5.3

Comment: ...which has its 5th birthday and even end-of-support deadline this year, so I dearly hope we do not need to keep pointing this out... ;)

Answer (score 0):

use callback function of array filter

```
<?php
function stripnull($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is odd
    return $var !== null;
}


$array1 = array("a"=>true, "b"=>false, "c"=>null);
```